# Bluetooth pairing in C on Linux

Tags: c, linux, bluetooth

I am looking for information, documentation, sample code or something else about the management of Bluetooth pairing/encryption in C under linux. Where can i find that ?

Regards,
Alban

Answer (score 3):

The dominant bluetooth stack at the moment is [Bluez](http://www.bluez.org/); a good tutorial can be found at [An Introduction to Bluetooth Programming](http://people.csail.mit.edu/albert/bluez-intro/)

Comment: I use Bluez till now, and yes this tutorial is a good point to start, but unfortunately, it doesn't get into pairing/encryption.

Answer (score 2):

You can use hciconfig, which is a tool supplied as part of BlueZ.  The actual pairing / encryption is done inside the BT device, not the host stack.  You just configure the BT device using hciconfig to tell it whether to do authentication and encryption.

See [hciconfig man page](http://linux.die.net/man/8/hciconfig), specifically the auth/noauth and encrypt/noencrypt commands

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK the pairing API is via D-Bus, which can be accessed in C.

See e.g. http://git.kernel.org/?p=bluetooth/bluez.git;a=blob;f=doc/adapter-api.txt;hb=HEAD and http://git.kernel.org/?p=bluetooth/bluez.git;a=blob;f=doc/agent-api.txt;hb=HEAD